# Procedure or function 'insert_into' expects parameter '@FirstName', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass info to my database using a stored procedures but keep getting that error. When I test I have entered a value but still no dice. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here? I have checked for spelling errors and all of that. I have no idea what I did wrong. Thanks in advance

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_into] 
    (@FirstName varchar(20),
     @LastName varchar(20),
     @Email varchar(50),
     @caldate1 date,
     @caldate2 date,
     @id int output)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customers (FirstName, Lastname, Email, caldate1, caldate2)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @caldate1, @caldate2)

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    RETURN @id
END
```

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Firstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Lastname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="go" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lbloutput" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Server side code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conn = "";
    conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString();

    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);

    try
    {
        if (Firstname.Text != " ")
        {
            objsqlconn.Open();

            SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("insert_into", objsqlconn);
            SqlParameter id = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
            id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter FirstName = objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            FirstName.Value = Firstname.Text;

            SqlParameter LastName = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            LastName.Value = Lastname.Text;                    

            SqlParameter Email = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            Email.Value = email.Text;

            SqlParameter caldate1 = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@caldate1", SqlDbType.Date);
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            caldate1.Value = dt.Date;

            SqlParameter caldate2 = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@caldate2", SqlDbType.Date);
            DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            caldate2.Value = dt2.Date;

            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            lbloutput.Text = "Record inserted successfully. ID = " + id.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        objsqlconn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.AddWithValue` for `@FirstName` (the only parameter you're using this for) - but you're not really calling an overload that provides a value (that's a [bad idea anyway](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)), but you're specifying the datatype of the parameter (which is a **good** thing!). SO I believe if you change the `.AddWithValue` to jsut `.Add` for the `@FirstName` parameter, you should be fine

Change this:

```
SqlParameter FirstName = objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
FirstName.Value = Firstname.Text;
```

to:

```
SqlParameter FirstName = objcmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
FirstName.Value = Firstname.Text;
```

**Update:** as @DanGuzman correctly points out in the comments - you also need to tell your `SqlCommand` that you're about to call a stored procedure:

```
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("insert_into", objsqlconn);
objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: I believe `objcmd.CommandType` needs to be set to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` too.

Comment: I did have it as just .Add but I changed it .addwithvalue to test it and forgot to change it back. It gave me the same error @mar_s. I don't have that line anywhere in my code

Comment: setting objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure was what I was missing. Thank you Dan :D